# Adapter View is refreshing while on notifying

Tags: android, adapter

I have List View like Facebook, it has video View and like button etc, what is my problem, while video is playing on list if that time i will click on like button video is getting started again from starting,

what is my requirement, If video is playing and if i click on like button video should interrupted.

How can I solve this issue?